# Create a unique node and relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i'm trying to create a unique attribute on a node with a relationship.  The problem is the unique attribute is only unique for label 'B' i need it to also be unique for label 'A'.  Is it possible to have a unique constraint across many labels?

```
MATCH (user:A { userId: '57e3c97c6a430242328878ec' })
CREATE UNIQUE (user)-[:KNOWS]-(telephone:B{telephone: '+447735150512'})
RETURN telephone
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the property should be unique on nodes of labels A and B (possibly more?)

There isn't support for that right now, but there is a workaround, though it requires some upkeep on your part.

Nodes can have multiple labels. So if you create a label that is additionally applied to nodes of multiple other labels (a superlabel C that is applied to nodes with label A and B), you can create a unique constraint on C for that property. You will have to make sure that all A and B nodes are additionally labeled with C, but when that is in place, then you will not be able to create a new A or B node (additionally labeled with C) with a property that is already in use on another C node.

The disadvantage of this approach is that if you create an A or B node, but forget to also label it with C, the unique constraint will not be enforced, since that only happens with C nodes.

Comment: Thanks, examples to the solution are here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7814